# C# Event right before and after calling Debugger.Break()?

Tags: c#, debugging, events, break, breakpoints

I'm debugging an AI bot that's being fed 'replay' input data to make it replay a previously played match. Each turn is limited to a certain amount of time, which the bot uses to calculate its remaining time for the current turn; this lets it determine how to use the remaining turn time. Now, what I'd like to do, is keep track of the amount of time spent debugging (the total amount time spent in breakpoints for that turn), so I can add that to the remaining time to make it seem like execution never paused.

Originally, I tried using something like this:

```
private DateTime turnTimeStarted;
public TimeSpan TurnTimeRemaining
{
    get { return (turnTimeStarted + TurnTime + TimeSpentInDebugger) - 
                      DateTime.Now; }
}

private DateTime debugStartTime;
private bool inDebugger = false;

private TimeSpan timeSpentInDebugger = new TimeSpan();
public TimeSpan TimeSpentInDebugger
{
    get
    {
         if (!inDebugger) 
             return timeSpentInDebugger;
         return timeSpentInDebugger + (DateTime.Now - debugStartTime);
    }
}

public void Break()
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        debugStartTime = DateTime.Now;
        inDebugger = true;

        Debugger.Break();

        inDebugger = false;
        timeSpentInDebugger += DateTime.Now - debugStartTime;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it breaks on the actual `Debugger.Break()` statement instead of the `Break()` method call, so I end up outside the context of the code I want to debug.

What I'm looking for is something like a set of events that is triggered right before and after calling `Debugger.Break` to detect the times for entering and leaving breakpoints. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Debug events are not observable in the program being debugged.  Use the debugger only to make your program functional.  And profile your program only without a debugger (using the Release build) so you can be sure that the jitter optimizer is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Stopwatch ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx ) class and start just before breaking, stop just after and add times as required.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at SlimTune: http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/ and this article about the DNProfiler by Matt Pietrek http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301725.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is old but I still didn't found better solution for this.

Regarding breaking in wrong context, you can solve this easily by exposing an `Action` property instead of a method:

```
public static class MyDebugger {
    public static Action Break => Debugger.Break;
}
```

Then debugger will stop at `MyDebugger.Break()` call instead of `Debugger.Break`.

You can store the time before returning the action but the main issue is you can't tell when the execution is actually resumed since the `Break()` only requests the stop and is not actually performing the debugging process.

To work around this I wrote a monitoring method that measures it's execution time and start it on a sperate thread when the property is accessed. When execution time is slow it considers it as time spend evaluation breakpoint, otherwise, when normal execution speed is detected for certain amount of time, the thread exits.

[I share it here](https://github.com/Audionysos/VariousIssues/blob/master/Net7/debuggerBreakTime/Debuger.cs)

With this you could calculate your time like this:

```
public TimeSpan TurnTimeRemaining
    => turnTimeStarted + TurnTime - Debuger.Now;
```

The problem with that is that you have to utilize the whole thread in order to get reasonably accurate measurements. It's not a big deal when you are actually stepping through the code but you will have the thread blocked for few seconds after resuming the application.

More importantly, you are not able to detect when debugger hits breakpoint set from the IDE if monitor is not turned on constantly.

To deal with that I wrote additional lazy monitor that runs on a task in slower interval but it is not that accurate and has it's own issues...

It's a shame the `Debugger` interface is so poor.